# PopState not firing after coming back from another site

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

My popstate event handler is defined thusly:

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (ev) { 
    alert('popstate');
    /* recompose dom */
});
```

It works fine while I am within my site as I use back and forward, however when I navigate to another site and then come back my event does not fire.

I assume this is by design based on the following comment on Mozilla Developer:

> Browsers tend to handle the popstate event differently on page load.
>   Chrome (prior to v34) and Safari (prior to 10.0) always emit a
>   popstate event on page load, but Firefox doesn't.

If this is the case, how do I get the most recent pushed state when coming back to my page from another site.

Comment: What is your understanding?

Comment: @destoryer updated wording

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out; pull the current page state from `history.state` on document ready and apply it.